# np.arange or np.arage ? Error:module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arage' when using plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I just ran into this error. Is it something wrong with my `NumPy` package?
If so, is there any way to fix this?
Thank you!!

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_compare,pred)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
#Normalize the confusion matrix by row(number of samples in each class)
cm_normalized = cm.astype("float")/cm.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(cm_normalized,products,title="normalized confusion matrix")
plt.show()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-73200f58ca39> in <module>()
      8 cm_normalized = cm.astype("float")/cm.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
      9 plt.figure()
---> 10 plot_confusion_matrix(cm_normalized,products,title="normalized confusion matrix")
     11 plt.show()

<ipython-input-3-db289f24b6ee> in plot_confusion_matrix(cm, names, title, cmap)
     17   plt.title(title)
     18   plt.colorbar()
---> 19   tick_marks = np.arage(len(names))
     20   plt.xticks(tick_marks,names,rotation=45)
     21   plt.yticks(tick_marks,names)

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arage'
```

Comment: @ggorlen. Probably just a typo, but it's  "arange" with one 'r' .

Comment: Can you provide a longer error stack ? It should point you to the line at which the error occurs. Most likely there is the suspected spelling error.

Comment: I sort of feel like it is "arrange". But the error tells me there is no "arage"..

Comment: @SeanZhang1997:  You have `np.arage` in your `plot_confusion_matrix` function. Replace that with `np.arange` and you should be good to go. (If you got the `plot_confusion_matrix` function from somewhere else, you may need to report the bug to the person who gave you that code.)

Comment: @Mark Dickinson I am using GoogleCOLAB. Is their numpy package initialized or it is using my package installed ?

Comment: @SeanZhang1997 It would help if you showed us all of your code. Where did you get `plot_confusion_matrix` from? Did you import it from somewhere, or is it code that you wrote? The problem is in that function, not in NumPy.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I think it is from`from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix`

Comment: That's a different function. I'm asking about `plot_confusion_matrix`, not `confusion_matrix`. You use it in the second-to-last line of the code snippet you show. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this was supposed to be [`np.arange()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

Could you tell me if you wrote that `plot_confusion_matrix(cm, names, title, cmap)` function? If yes, just change `tick_marks = np.arage(len(names))` with `tick_marks = np.arange(len(names))` and see if it works.

Please check also scikit-learn's own [`plot_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html).

If nothing works, please let us know your `numpy` and `scikit-learn` versions:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, I think I get where went wrong. This function is not from sklearn or numpy. It is from another file. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You can comment at [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Until then, please refrain from using the answer box to add comments. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that @ggorlen, though it seems to have solved the issue... how do you differ a comment from an answer?

Comment: No problem. Comments are the things you see below an answer or a question.

Comment: I understood that, I mean the _content_ of it.